# Syntax highlighting Markdown via Assemble.io - incomplete

Tags: node.js, markdown, assemble

Am I missing something? I have a rendering pipeline set up with `assemble.io` via an express server and everything is rendering as expected. However, when I add in bracket fences for Markdown there seems to be an issue with the syntax highlighting. It does drop the code into `<code>` and `<pre>` tags as expected and when I add in the language identifier after the top fence it does add in the `class="language-[LANG]` like you would think it would, however, it does nothing to the code within it (e.g. wrapping the tag elements, attributes, important names, etc. in span tags).

Is there a helper I need to add to the pipeline and pass the file through? So far I've tried adding `prismjs`, but that flattened the entire page into code (not ideal).

Result:
`&lt;a href=&quot;&quot;&gt;this is the link&lt;/a&gt;`

Expected:
`&lt;<span class="some-tag-class">a</span> <span class="some-name-class">href</span>=&quot;&quot;&gt;this is the link&lt;/a&gt;`

Comment: "*Is there a helper I need to add to the pipeline and pass the file through?*" Yes, but making library recommendations is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `markdown` documentation directly or at the `assemble.io` documentation does no good.

It's clearly listed on the `helper-markdown` [github](https://github.com/helpers/helper-markdown#api)/[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helper-markdown#api) sites respectivly.